# Haxe app and Gtk-WARNING on linux servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, debian, haxe

I'm trying a Haxe-compiled solution called FAR (Flash Archiver) created by Edwin Van Rijkom (http://code.google.com/p/vanrijkom-flashlibs/) wich uses a command-line tool for creating compressed archives.

When running the FAR tool locally on my ubuntu laptop, everything works fine.
When running remotely (terminal as Root) on my Ubuntu and Debian servers, it gives the following error:
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

I've tried to reach Edvin about this, but no response so far.
Maybe it has something to do with installation or user rights on the server?

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When logging in remotely, use the -X argument to ssh so X applications can reach your X display. You will need X11Forwarding enabled in /etc/ssh/sshd_config also, which by default it probably is.  Also, running ssh as root allows attackers to attempt to compromise your root account;  Especially if you are using password authentication instead of pub-key.